# How to import models in other projects in Django

Tags: python, django, model

Is it possible to import models from apps in different Django projects?

I hope to move some common models in a base projects from which every child projects can share the same data in these common models.

**Edit**

I have to place

```
from baseproject.appname.models import basemodel
```

before

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'childproject.settings'
from django.conf import settings
```

in child project to access the data in base model correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can turn a project-specific app into a standard Python package by moving it to `site-packages` (or wherever your Python install expects its modules) and breaking any links from it to other apps in the project. You can then import it as you would any Python module, in any project.

Comment: Hi Ignacia, the base project is already installed site-packages folder. The import statement "from baseproject.app.models import basemodel" works but when I tried to access data in basemodel, it keep showing "Table childproject.baseproject_basemodel doesn't exists".

Comment: It's not necessary to put the whole project in site-packages, just the app. Did you remember to add it to `INSTALLED_APPS` and do a syncdb?

Comment: @Ignacio, I just found the reason.